# Why does Response.Write() only write the first element in list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, .net-4.0

I am trying to write some syndication onto my page,

I use the .Net class to get the rss content into a list

```
<div>    
    <%
        var r = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create("http://www.huffingtonpost.com/feeds/verticals/small-business/index.xml");
        System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationFeed albums = System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationFeed.Load(r);
        r.Close(); 

        foreach (System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationItem album in albums.Items)
        {
            Response.Write(album.Title.Text);                        
        }                          
    %>
</div>
```

Well the `foreach` is only functioning as a **forfirst** here, because it only writes the first SyndicationItem in the list. As you can see, [there are many items in that list](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/feeds/verticals/small-business/index.xml). Where can be my mistake?

Just to make sure there is not only 1 item in my album list, I did a count on it.

```
<div>

        <%
            var r = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create("http://www.huffingtonpost.com/feeds/verticals/small-business/index.xml");
            System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationFeed albums = System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationFeed.Load(r);
            r.Close();
            int i = albums.Items.ToList().Count;

            Response.Write(i); 

          /*  foreach (System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationItem album in albums.Items)
            {
                Response.Write(album.Title.Text); 
            } */

         %>

    </div>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Is it writing only the first item in the list or only the *last* item in the list?

Comment: I have no doubt that it is writing _all_ items in the list - in other words, there is _only_ a single item in the list.

Comment: First, thought you might have been onto something there though.

Comment: @JohnSaunders http://www.huffingtonpost.com/feeds/verticals/small-business/index.xml 

Is there only one item in that list?

Comment: It doesn't matter what's in the XML. What matters is what's in memory when your code runs.  Set a breakpoint before the foreach and see what's in there.

Comment: Ok, there are 15 items in the list. See my edit of OP

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code (as it is above). To test, I just copied and pasted and get 15 items/titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am wondering if the title output your seeing is "small business on huffingtonpost.com".  If it is, then it is working correctly.  You have one item in the list with many entries.  Do another iteration inside your current iteration and you should be good to go.

[image: List of titles from huffingtonPost]

Update
I just pasted your code in a forms page and it came through with all 15 results.

Comment: No, the title output I see is

"John Mackey: The Future of Health Care and Free Enterprise CapitalismRestaurant Workers Deserve More Pay, ..... etc"

Comment: I updated my answer.  I pasted your code into a new forms app and it seems to work as you would expect.  You seem to be doing it correctly.  What version of .net are you developing with?

Comment: It turns out it worked in chrome and explorer and not firefox. Might have been a caching issue or something, although I thought debugging automatically ignored caches. Oh well.